# filter array function for an array inside set state is not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Trying to get an an onclick function to delete an item (that's been clicked) from an array.

However, it doesnt delete anything. setListOfDocs is supposed to set the listOfDocs array with the clicked item gone (onClick function is a filter)

It does not work. There's no error in the console. I don't know why it's not updating the state so that the listOfDocs is the new filtered array (with the clicked item removed from the array).

Im using material ui.

```js
    function NewMatterDocuments() {
    const [listOfDocs, setListOfDocs] = useState(['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4']);
    const [disableButton, toggleDisableButton] = useState(false);
    const [displayTextField, toggleDisplayTextField] = useState('none');
    const [textInputValue, setTextInputValue] = useState();

    const buttonClick = () => {
        toggleDisableButton(true);
        toggleDisplayTextField('box');
    };
//this function works
    const handleEnter = ({ target }) => {
        setTextInputValue(target.value);
        const newItem = target.value;
        setListOfDocs((prev) => {
            return [...prev, newItem];
        });
        setTextInputValue(null);
    }; //

//this function does not work....which is weird because it pretty much
// does the same thing as the previous function except it deletes an item
// instead of adding it to the array. Why does the previous function work
// but this one doesnt?

    const deleteItem = ({ currentTarget }) => {
        const deletedId = currentTarget.id;
        const result = listOfDocs.filter((item, index) => index !== deletedId); 
        setListOfDocs(result)
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <Typography variant="body2">
                <FormGroup>
                    <Grid container spacing={3}>
                        <Grid item xs={6}>
                            <Grid item xs={6}>
                                Document Type
                            </Grid>
                            {listOfDocs.map((item, index) => {
                                return (
                                    <ListItem id={index} secondaryAction={<Checkbox />}>
                                        <ListItemAvatar>
                                            <Avatar>
                                                <DeleteIcon id={index} onClick={deleteItem} />
                                            </Avatar>
                                        </ListItemAvatar>
                                        <ListItemButton>
                                            <ListItemText id={index} primary={item} />
                                        </ListItemButton>
                                    </ListItem>
                                );
                            })}
                            <List sx={{ width: '100%', bgcolor: 'background.paper' }}>
                                <Button disabled={!disableButton ? false : true} color="inherit" onClick={buttonClick}>
                                    Add
                                </Button>
                                <ListItem sx={{ display: `${displayTextField}` }} id={uuid()} key={uuid()}>
                                    <TextField
                                        id="standard-basic"
                                        label="Additional Document"
                                        variant="standard"
                                        value={textInputValue}
                                        onKeyDown={(e) => {
                                            e.key === 'Enter' && handleEnter(e);
                                        }}
                                    ></TextField>
                                </ListItem>
                            </List>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </FormGroup>
            </Typography>
        </div>
    );
}

export default NewMatterDocuments;
```

I tried to change the function that wasnt working into the following:

```js
const deleteItem = ({ currentTarget }) => {
    setListOfDocs((prev) => {
        prev.filter((item, index) => index != currentTarget.id);
    });
};
```

It gives the error
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')"
The next map function inside the jsx doesnt work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return your data after filter:

```js
const deleteItem = ({ currentTarget }) => {
    setListOfDocs((prev) => {
        return prev.filter((item, index) => index != currentTarget.id);
    });
};
```

**Update:**

There is a problem with your first try. The **currentTarget.id** field is string but in your filter method, you're comparing it with the index (which is number) with **!==** which also checks types of the 2 variables.

So you can fix it by replacing !== with != or converting string to number.

Comment: Do know why the deleteItem function (in the original code) did not work? I understand why the second one wasnt working cause it was an arrow function that needed an explicit return...but I cant see why the first one didnt work....Thank you

Comment: @chu8 I updated my answer. Please check it now.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you made a small mistake in your filtering function: you are comparing item **index** with **deletedId**, where you should compare **item** with **deletedId**

This should be correct:

```
const deleteItem = ({ currentTarget }) => {
        const deletedId = currentTarget.id;
        const result = listOfDocs.filter((item, index) => item !== deletedId); 
        setListOfDocs(result)
    };
```

Comment: ? I don't think that's correct. My goal is to compare the index with deleteId. I dont want to compare the item. If I was comparing the item I would use "item !==currentTarget.value"  I'm intentionally wanting to compare the index with the deleteId. The index are numbers and so are deleteId. item is not a number. They are strings.

Comment: What's the output of `console.log(deletedId)`, and after `console.log(result)`?

Comment: console.log(deletedId) is literally just the index of the target that was clicked - it gives the index item that was clicked which is either 0,1,2 or 3 depending on which item of the array was clicked. The console.log(result) just gives the array. ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4']